# How to convert this timestamp in PLSQL?

Tags: sql, plsql, sql-timestamp

Using PL/SQL I have a `TIMESTAMP(6)` like this: `21-APR-22 02.25.00.000000 PM`.

I need to convert it to format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` (EX: `2022-04-21 14:25:00`).

EDIT: I also need to store it as a VARCHAR

```
declare ts TIMESTAMP(6) :='21-APR-22 02.25.00.000000 PM'; 
dt VARCHAR(102); 
begin 
  dt:= TO_CHAR('19-APR-21 02.25.00.000000 PM','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'); 
  dbms_output.put_line(dt); 
  commit; 
END; 
[Error] Execution (50: 1): ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512: at line 5
```

Comment: Timestamps, dates are not persisted in a "format", so what you are showing is the display representation. in the client software you are using, which may be default formatted based on NLS parameters.   If you want to show in a different format, then call to_char function on the timestamp data type with the format specifier  you show. A [mcve] would be helpful

Comment: declare
ts TIMESTAMP(6) :='21-APR-22 02.25.00.000000 PM';
dt VARCHAR(102);
begin
dt:= TO_CHAR('19-APR-21 02.25.00.000000 PM','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
dbms_output.put_line(dt);
commit;
END; [Error] Execution (50: 1): ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 5

Comment: Note that you do not need to specify the timestamp literal the way you do (which likely causes the pl/sql error). See the linked example in my answer, or consult the oracle docs.

Comment: @Schwab: your code looks so much better in the question, then in the comments....

Comment: [Documentation page for literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Literals.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
TO_CHAR(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

with `ts` holding the timestamp value you want to turn into a varchar value matching to the desired format.

See [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ce1017679e36b423769dba417d31d0bb)  (on dbfiddle.uk).

Answer (score 0):

```
declare ts TIMESTAMP(6) :='21-APR-22 02.25.00.000000 PM'; 
dt VARCHAR(102); 
begin 
  dt:= TO_CHAR(ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'); 
  dbms_output.put_line(dt); 
  commit; 
END;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?